# Propositional logic — How to introduce $P$ into this proof? Should I use conditional exchange?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

I have to prove the following without using conditional proofs (assumption) or indirect proofs.

[image]

I managed to use rules of inference to deduce $Q$, but I have no clue on how to actually get $P$ introduced into this, since it isn't contained in any of the premises.

My proof so far:

1. $\neg(R \vee S) \rightarrow (\neg S \wedge \neg Q)$
2. $\neg Q \rightarrow S$
3. $\neg R \wedge \neg S \hspace{10 mm}/\therefore P \rightarrow Q$
4. $\neg(R \vee S) \hspace{10 mm} \text{3. De Morgan's law}$
5. $\neg S \wedge \neg Q \hspace{10 mm} \text{1, 4 Modus ponens}$
6. $\neg Q \hspace{21 mm} \text{5 Simplification}$
7. $S \hspace{23 mm} \text{2, 6 Modus ponens}$
8. $\neg S \hspace{21 mm} \text{5 Simplification}$
9. $Q \hspace{23 mm} \text{2, 8 Modus tollens}$

Comment: It depends on the rules... But $Q \vDash P \to Q$.

Comment: You can use [Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction) to get $\lnot P \lor Q$ from 4q4 and then [Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference))